# Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

When I use a select2 (input) in bootstrap modal, I can't type anything into it. It's like disabled? Outside the modal select2 works fine.

[image]

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/byJy8/1/
code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Panel</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 800px">          
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="vdn_number">Numer</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <!-- seleect2 -->
                <input name="vdn_number" type="hidden" id="vdn_number"  class="input-large" required=""  />
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>    
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$("#vdn_number").select2({
    placeholder: "00000",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "getAjaxData/",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, // search term
                col: 'vdn'
            };
        },
        results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

answers:

here you can find a quick [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487440/1251563)

and here is 'the right way': [Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal/19574076#19574076)

Comment: That is, removing the attribute *tabindex="-1"* from the element.

Comment: [dboswell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33884094/1469494) is the right solution, BUT, the `dropdownParent` should not be on the root div, but deeper, for example the div with class `modal-content`, otherwise the dropdown positions get messed up when scrolling the modal.

Comment: [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741855/how-to-load-select2-in-partial-view/71118344#71118344) which worked with me

Answer (score 731, accepted):

Ok, I've got it to work.

change

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Panel</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 800px">
```

to

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Panel</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 800px">
```

(remove  **tabindex="-1"** from modal)

Comment: May be there another solution? Because modal window then won't close by Esc key.

Comment: removing tabindex="-1" didn't work form me. I've just changed  <div class="modal-body"> to <div class="modal-body" style="overflow:hidden;">

Comment: Please select pymarco answer as the correct one, this solutions breaks ESC key, his doesn't. Nice try though.

Comment: @woto have you find any other solution? I had the same issue like yours. after removing `tabindex="-1"` my model did not close on `Esc` key.

Comment: Is there any sideeffect of removing taxindex?

Comment: It won't work: It'll show other select2 dropdown list present on the page.

Comment: $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { }; This may be able to be solved using a method found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050641/month-select-in-datepicker-inside-a-bootstrap-modal-wont-work-in-firefox

Comment: Tested with Bootstrap 5 vbeta2 modal and Select2 v4.0.13. This solution works perfectly and modal can still get closed with Esc key.

Answer (score 370):

**For Select2 v4:**

Use `dropdownParent` to attach the dropdown to the modal dialog, rather than the HTML body.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select id="select2insidemodal" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            ...
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select2insidemodal").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#myModal")
  });
});

</script>
```

This will attach the Select2 dropdown so it falls within the DOM of the modal rather than to the HTML body (the default). See https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement

Comment: This worked for me (with v4.0.2), but I had to use `dropdownParent: $("#myModal")`, not `dropdownParent: "#myModal"`.

Comment: @Kevin Brown: your update on the post is not accurate as `dropdownParent: $("#myModal")` is **STILL** required for enabling typing in on modal using version **v4.0.1**; I've just run the test. You may revert your update in order to make @dboswell's answer still relevant and meaningful.

Comment: @nyed the only edit I made was that I forced dropdownParent to take a jQuery object. The update was already there, and I'm not in a position to verify it.

Comment: @KevinBrown: Ok; your input makes sense. The misleading **UPDATE** was rather made by @dboswell; not you. Apologies.

Comment: FWIW, in my case I needed to set  the dropdownParent to the body of the modal, attaching it to the modal itself did not bring the z-index up high enough. e.g. dropdownParent: $('.modal-body', '#myModal')

Comment: Worked also for me instead of removing the `tabindex="-1"`

Comment: @DrewInTheMountains I also had issues setting the `dropdownParent` to the root of the modal, it's indeed better to choose the body, otherwise you get really bad positioning bugs when scrolling. I set mine to the div with class `modal-content` and it works like a charm!

Comment: For those that had an issue with it, but are reusing a module in different locations, you can attach the dropdownParent to the div encapsulating the select2, and then it works properly at all locations you use it, whether in the modal or the page. It worked for me, but it might have other issues that I'm not aware of.

Comment: This is the solution if you have the select2 dropdown located within a fancybox v3!

Comment: If you set the dropdownParent to the modal you will have trouble when your modal will become scrollable. The select2's dropdown parent should be set to the input parent

Comment: this worked for me `dropdownParent: $("#myModelDialog"),`

Comment: Works in bootstrap 5 as well

Answer (score 225):

I found a solution to this on github for select2

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1436

For bootstrap 3, the solution is:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Bootstrap 4 renamed the `enforceFocus` method to `_enforceFocus`, so you'll need to patch that instead:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Explanation copied from link above:

> Bootstrap registers a listener to the focusin event which checks whether the focused element is either the overlay itself or a descendent of it - if not it just refocuses on the overlay. With the select2 dropdown being attached to the body this effectively prevents you from entering anything into the textfield.
>
> You can quickfix this by overwriting the enforceFocus function which registers the event on the modal

Comment: I just fixed this for using CKEditor inside a Bootstrap 2.3.2 modal window.  This function is called a *lot*, so if you modify the if statement you have to be really careful not to bash your browser; I suggest placing any addition clauses inside the existing if - not appending them to that if.  (e.g. if (existing conditions) { if (your conditions) {   Hope that helps.

Comment: where do I put this code and what function should it address? Sorry, JS noob here, I tried making this a part of the select2 JS or placing it at top / end of the page, all without success. `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;`

Comment: in bootstrap 4, instead of globally overwriting the enforceFocus function..If we set `data-focus="false"` to a modal (`<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" data-focus="false" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">`) _enforceFocus will never be called for this modal.
tested in bootstrap 4.1.3 and it worked...original answer https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19971#issuecomment-275901368

Comment: for fix scroll bug and search input bug in bootstrap modal you see my answer in page 2

Comment: Complementing @Ashokbharathi. If you need to apply this effect to a single modal instance (having access to base code), you can inspect for `data-focus` attribute on bootstrap.js:1011 and wrap the method call into an if statement. Tested on 3.3.7

Comment: I started getting ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Constructor')``` error in the console. I am using bootstrap5. I tried the bs4 code above. In bs5 everything is broken in the modal, especially select2 and datepicker. This constant when appending the content in modal.

Answer (score 75):

Set the dropdownParent. I had to set it on .modal-content within the modal or the text would end up centered.

```
$("#product_id").select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#myModal .modal-content')
});
```

Comment: The `.modal-content` really make a difference. Thanks for pointing out 

Comment: If you using this for multiple modals you can use `dropdownParent: $(".modal-body , .modal-body1")`

Comment: works also in Bootstrap 5

Comment: THIS MUST BE ACCEPTED ANSWER. Thanks, Bezz.

Answer (score 54):

Just remove `tabindex="-1"` and add style `overflow:hidden`

Here is an example:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <!---content modal here -->
</div>
```

Comment: it works but when I have long modal I can't scroll down !

Comment: Tried removing the tabindex but was not enought. Adding overflow: hidden is useful if the modal box is long...

Comment: Worked for me removing the tab index attribute.

Comment: Just FYI: removing tab-index attr will remove the ability of closing modal popup by esc button.

Comment: if you are using yii2 bootstrap modal use options settings:
'options' => ['tabindex' => false, "style"=>"overflow:hidden;"],

Answer (score 44):

```
.select2-close-mask{
    z-index: 2099;
}
.select2-dropdown{
    z-index: 3051;
}
```

This is my solution with select2 4.0.0. Just override the css right below the select2.css import. 
Please make sure the z-index is greater than your dialog or modal. I just add 2000 on the default ones. Cause my dialogs' z-index are about 1000.

Comment: None of the solutions worked for select2 4.0.0 except this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The same issue occurs if Select2 (v4.0.0) is in a popover. In `bootstrap.css` the z-index of `.popover` is set to 1060 so this fix works as well. I like it because it's simple and it solves the problem the same way the problem was created: z-index set in a style sheet.

Comment: I've added the above in my css file, but it has no changes. I'm using jQuery Mobile. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Sahil 1. make sure it's successfully overridden the original ones. simple way is add this after all the default css files2.check the z-index, ensure it's larger than the dialog's

Comment: Remove tabindex="-1" from modal to make this solution work.

Comment: This is awesome and simple solution. Other solutions did work in some places but in my case none of them was working. This worked like a champ!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Answer that worked for me found here: https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41

```
$('select').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#my_amazing_modal')
});
```

Also doesn't require removing the `tabindex`.

Answer (score 18):

In my case I had the same problem with two modals and all was resolved using:

```
$('.select2').each(function() { 
    $(this).select2({ dropdownParent: $(this).parent()});
})
```

As in the project issue [#41](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41) an user said.

Comment: I added `dropdownParent: $('#my_modal .select2_parent')` as your answer and `.select2-container{top:100% !important;}` to fix my same issue. Tried all the solutions, but only solved by this.

Comment: Best solution for multiple modal. 
Thanks

Answer (score 15):

According to the official select2 documentation this issue occurs because Bootstrap modals tend to steal focus from other elements outside of the modal.

By default Select2 attaches the dropdown menu to the  element and it is considered "outside of the modal".

Instead attach the dropdown to the modal itself with the dropdownParent setting:

```
$('#myModal').select2({
   dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
});
```

See reference: https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems

Comment: Good. it was not working with magnific popup, now after adding dropdownParent option its working fine.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, updating `z-index` for `.select2-container` should do the trick. Make sure your modal's `z-index` is lower than select2's.

```
.select2-container {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Updated:
In case above code doesn't work properly, also remove tabindexes from your modal as  @breq suggested

Comment: you need to implement this with @breq answer to make it works.

Comment: I find it quite nice and easy over attaching to parent model.

Comment: Ok. But, z-index style affects visibility of other raised elements such as side nav.

Answer (score 12):

This Problem Sloved Working For Me Single Jquery Function

```
$('#myModal .select2').each(function() {  
   var $p = $(this).parent(); 
   $(this).select2({  
     dropdownParent: $p  
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 11):

For bootstrap3 versions, just use this code on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
});
```

Comment: The proper function name is "$(document).ready". So code should be like:
$(document).ready(function () { $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { }; });

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and I fixed with

```
    $('#CompId').select2({
              dropdownParent: $('#AssetsModal')
    });
```

and modal with select

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="AssetsModal" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" 
    aria-hidden="true"  style="overflow:hidden;" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" >Добави активи</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form" action="?action=dma_act_documents_assets_insert&Id=<?=$ID?>" 
                  method="post" name="dma_act_documents_assets_insert" 
                  id="dma_act_documents_assets_insert">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Актив:</label>
                  <span style="color: red">*</span>
                          <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single col-sm-12" 
                                 name="CompId" id="CompId">
                                  <option></option>
                          </select>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I don't know why the select menu is smaller than other fields
[image]

and it starting like that when start using select2. When I remove it, all is ok.

Is there some one to share some experince about that.

Thanks.

Comment: use style `width: 100%` and it will be in full width.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.select2me').select2({
        dropdownParent: $(this).find('.modal-content')
    });
})
```

Comment: Worked for bootstrap 5

Comment: Best solution so far as it only changes the parent of the select inside the modal.

Answer (score 6):

to use bootstrap 4.0 with server-side(ajax or json data inline), you need to add all of this:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```

and then when modal is open, create the select2:

```
  // when modal is open
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('select').select2({
                  // ....
            });
  });
```

Comment: instead of globally disabling focus functionality of bootstrap modal, you can specify data-focus="false" attribute on modal html code. [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#options)

Comment: None of other answers worked for me except this one, if you are opening the modal manually then this answer is the one to go

Comment: I just added " $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {}; this line and it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: the solution worked with bootstrap 4. others didnt for me

Answer (score 5):

change **select2.css** file

```
z-index: 9998;
...
z-index: 9999;
...
z-index: 10000;
```

to

```
z-index: 10000;
...
z-index: 10001;
...
z-index: 10002;
```

Comment: That's the only one works for me (jquery-ui-1.10.3.css, jquery-ui-1.9.1.js and select2 3.4.0). I have 2 jquery UI dialogs one on top of the other and select2 on the second one. Also I have put   //allow interaction of select2, date and time picker on jQuery UI dialog
  $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(e) {
   return !!$(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog, .ui-datepicker, .select2-drop').length;
  }; I have no idea if this help or not.

Answer (score 5):

Just to understand better how tabindex elements works to complete accepted answer :

> The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to sequential keyboard navigation, and if so, at what position. It can take several values:
>     -a negative value means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;
>   
>     -0 means that the element should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but its relative order is defined by the platform convention;
>   
>     -a positive value means should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation; its relative order is defined by the value of the attribute: the sequential follow the increasing number of the tabindex. If several elements share the same tabindex, their relative order follows their relative position in the document.

from : [Mozilla Devlopper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Answer (score 4):

Remove `tabindex="-1"` from modal. I checked this solution and it's worked.

Ref: https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41

Answer (score 4):

This will work for all

```
body .select2-container {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

please note to add width also to fix the interface:

```js
$('.select2').select2({
    width: '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Select2 Bootstrap 5 Theme](https://github.com/apalfrey/select2-bootstrap-5-theme) in **Bootstrap Modal** like this:

1. fix `select2 & bootstrap` modal **search input** bug.
2. fix `select2 & bootstrap` modal **scroll bug after select option**.

```js
jQuery(function() {

  $('.my-select2').each(function() {
    $(this).select2({
      theme: "bootstrap-5",
      dropdownParent: $(this).parent(), // fix select2 search input focus bug
    })
  })

  // fix select2 bootstrap modal scroll bug
  $(document).on('select2:close', '.my-select2', function(e) {
    var evt = "scroll.select2"
    $(e.target).parents().off(evt)
    $(window).off(evt)
  })

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.2.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Select2 v4.1

          <select class="my-select2">
            <option>Test 1</option>
            <option>Test 2</option>
            <option>Test 3</option>
            <option>Test 4</option>
            <option>Test 5</option>
            <option>Test 6</option>
            <option>Test 7</option>
            <option>Test 8</option>
            <option>Test 9</option>
            <option>Test 10</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a problem with the **iPad** keyboard which **hide** the **bootstrap modal** while clicking on the **select2** input, you can resolve this by adding the following rule **after** the initialization of the `select2` input :

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)) {
   var styleEl = document.createElement('style'), styleSheet;
   document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
   styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
   styleSheet.insertRule(".modal { position:absolute; bottom:auto; }", 0);
   document.body.scrollTop = 0; // Only for Safari
}
```

Taken from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1812#issuecomment-135119475

**EDIT:** If your options are not shown properly, you need to use the `dropdownParent` attribute when initializing `select2` :

```
$(".select2").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#YOURMODALID")
});
```

Good luck (:

Answer (score 3):

Based on @pymarco answer I wrote this solution, it's not perfect but solves the select2 focus problem and maintain tab sequence working inside modal

```
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
        $(document)
        .off('focusin.bs.modal') // guard against infinite focus loop
        .on('focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
            if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length && !$(e.target).closest('.select2-dropdown').length) {
                this.$element.trigger('focus')
            }
        }, this))
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this generally in my project by overloading the `select2`-function.  Now it will check if there is no dropdownParent and if the function is called on an element that has a parent of the type `div.modal`.  If so, it will add that modal as the parent for the dropdown.

This way, you don't have to specify it every time you create a select2-input-box.

```js
(function(){
    var oldSelect2 = jQuery.fn.select2;
    jQuery.fn.select2 = function() {
        const modalParent = jQuery(this).parents('div.modal').first();
        if (arguments.length === 0 && modalParent.length > 0) {
            arguments = [{dropdownParent: modalParent}];
        } else if (arguments.length === 1
                    && typeof arguments[0] === 'object'
                    && typeof arguments[0].dropdownParent === 'undefined'
                    && modalParent.length > 0) {
            arguments[0].dropdownParent = modalParent;
        }
        return oldSelect2.apply(this,arguments);
    };
    // Copy all properties of the old function to the new
    for (var key in oldSelect2) {
        jQuery.fn.select2[key] = oldSelect2[key];
    }
})();
```

Comment: This actually was the only solution i got to work.. I am using Metronic HTML theme probably why

Answer (score 3):

Use this code on your page

```
$(function () {
    $(".select2").select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
    });

    $("#myModal").on('change', '#vdn_number', function () {
        var term = $(this).val();
        ajax: ({
            url: "getAjaxData/",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                    col: 'vdn'
                };
            },
            results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                return { results: data };
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I think this will help you

Comment: select2 works itself when we place the component on the main page, whereas on the model it doesn't therefore the answer `$(".select2").select2({  dropdownParent: $('#myModal')  });` helps to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#IlceId").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: false,
    dropdownParent: $("#IlceId").parent(),
    escapeMarkup: function (m) {
        return m;
    },
});
```

this code is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I know I'm late to the party. But let me share with you what worked for me.
The tabindex and z-index solutions did not work for me.

Setting the parent of the select element worked as per the [common problems](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems) listed on select2 site.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery mobile popup you must rewrite _handleDocumentFocusIn function:

```js
$.mobile.popup.prototype._handleDocumentFocusIn = function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.select2-dropdown').length) return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using jQuery Mobile and have embedded Select2 in a popup. The code you have provided works good on a PC browser. But when I run this code on a mobile browser, the popup closes and reopens when any value is selected. Can you suggest any changes I need to make?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the `select2` in `bootstrap modal`, and the solution was to remove the `overflow-y: auto;` and `overflow: hidden`; from `.modal-open` and `.modal classes`

Here is the example of using `jQuery` to remove the `overflow-y`:

```
$('.modal').css('overflow-y','visible');
$('.modal').css('overflow','visible');
```

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem before , i am using yii2 and i solved it this way

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a semi-related issue in an application so I'll put in my 2c.

I have multiple modals with forms containing select2 widgets.  Opening modal A, then another modal inside modal A, would cause select2 widgets inside modal B to disappear and fail to initialize.

Each of these modals were loading the forms via ajax.

The solution was to remove the forms from the dom when closing a modal.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function(e) {
    // make sure we don't leave any select2 widgets around 
    $(this).find('.my-form').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call select2 trigger again inside your $(document)

```
$(".select2").select2({ 
                width: '120' 
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't stuck your dropdown to the modal as suggested in most of the answer.
If your select2 is at the bottom of the modal and you need to scroll down to find it then you will have a dropdown's position problem because you stuck it on the modal.

Instead of this you should set the dropdown parent to the input parent. In your case it should look like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#vdn_number").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#vdn_number").parent()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just get it working by including **select2.min.css**

Try iy out

My modal html of bootstrap 3 is

```
<div id="changeTransportUserRequestPopup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 40%!important; ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3>Warning</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="changeTransportUserRequestPopupBody">
                <select id="cbTransport" class="js-example-basic-single" name="cbTransport" style="width:100%!important;"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="noPost" class="btn btn-default" name="postConfirm" value="false" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" id="yesChangeTransportPost" class="btn btn-success" name="yesChangeTransportPost" value="true" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using `stisla` and use firemodal :

```
$('#modal-create-promo').click(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $('#fire-modal-1').removeAttr('tabindex');
    });
});

    $("#modal-create-promo").fireModal({
    ...
});
```

It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

fix for Select2 search input not working in Bootstrap Modal - just temporary delete attribute "tabindex" when your drop down is open

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".select2-with-data-js").each(function (index) {
            const $select2 = $(this);

            $select2.select2().on("select2:opening", 
            function(){
                $("#modal--dealer-address").removeAttr("tabindex", "-1");
            }).on("select2:close", 
            function(){
                $("#modal--dealer-address").attr("tabindex", "-1");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case i did this and it works. I use bundle to load it and in this case it worked for me

```
 $(document).on('select2:select', '#Id_Producto', function (evt) {
   // Here your code...
  });
```