# Select2 not working inside bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to use `select2` inside bootstrap modal but it is not getting the focus automatically as well as down and up arrows are not working for the populated list.

The same select2 works when I put it outside the modal popup.

When I searched, I found many are facing this same problem and found this post

[Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal)

I implemented both the solutions from it

1. Removed `tabindex` from modal popup.
2. Commented code of `enforceFocus` function in modal.js file.

But it is still not working! Any idea what I could still be missing?

**Edit1**

It works on `firefox` when `tabindex` is removed from the modal div but not with `IE9`

**Edit2**

I found that removing `tabindex` is actually not getting recognized by `IE9` because I can still hide the popup by escape key in IE but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 18):

> Use bellow code. This will solve your bug.

```
$('select').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#my_amazing_modal')
});
```

Comment: If you using this for multiple modals you can use `dropdownParent: $(".modal-body , .modal-body1")`

Answer (score 16):

place this somewhere in your JS:

```
   //fix modal force focus
   $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
      var that = this;
      $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
         if ($(e.target).hasClass('select2-input')) {
            return true;
         }

         if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
            that.$element.focus();
         }
      });
   };
```

Answer (score 6):

I changed:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

to the following:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

That is, removing the attribute `tabindex="-1"` from the element.

Comment: Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="select">
    <select type="text" class="form-control" id="helloselect" data-width="100%" name="helloselect">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>Hola</option>
        <option>Hallo</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and the script

```
$("#helloselect").select2({dropdownParent: $("#select")});
```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for it and came across this one:

Worked for me on document ready for all select2

```
 $('select:not(.normal)').each(function () {
            $(this).select2({
                dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
            });
        });
```

Taken from:
https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41

Comment: This worked. I added an `id` to the main container and used the same as the answer. `dropdownParent`: $('#new_appended_container')

Answer (score 2):

I tried to set z-index for select2 dropdown option, and it worked for me. Here is what I did:

```css
.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open  {
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick, and it worked for me

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;
```

Answer (score 1):

the attribute tabindex='-1' in bootstrap modal prevents any element outside modal being reachable or focused by tab key. It is useful for limit tabs only on modal, for accessibility. But elements created by selec2 are children of document. 
You need to set dropdownParent to your modal

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("select").select2({dropdownParent: $("#myModal")});

    $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
      $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    });
  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <a href="" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Convert to popup</a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Bootsrap4 Modal Label</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="PopupWrapper">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>red</option>
              <option>blue</option>
              <option>green</option>
              <option>orange</option>
              <option>yellow</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/genigicuco/1/edit?html,js,output)

[meaning of tabindex=-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911355/whats-the-tabindex-1-in-bootstrap-for)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dropdownid').select2({
  dropdownParent: $('#modalid')
 });
```

Above code works for me, try this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use data attribute settings:
data-dropdown-parent="#bs-modal-id"

```
<select class="form-control" data-dropdown-parent="#bs-modal-id"></select>
```

Comment: easy solution works on laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

**I was facing with the same problem I just add the below code and it worked**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('.select2').each(function() {
              $(this).select2({
                  dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
              });
          })
      });
```

Comment: One of the best working answers on this issue. I was facing this problem in bootstrap modal with multiple instances. You are a CHAMP!

Comment: Furthermore, this one works great and equally good for Single or Multiple Dropdowns in Bootstrap forms with and without Bootstrap Modal!!!

Answer (score 0):

Dear all no need to take tabindex="-1" out there simple CSS solution.
Here we go:

```
.page-body .select2-drop {z-index: 10052;}
.select2-drop-mask {z-index: 10052;}
```

And you are done. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.select2-with-search').select2({
      placeholder: 'Choose one',
      searchInputPlaceholder: 'Search options',
   dropdownParent: $('.modal')
   });
```

us this <div class="**modal**"

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"  data-backdrop="">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
```

and use this    <select class="form-control  **select2-with-search**"

```
<select class="form-control wd-250 select2-with-search">
                     <option label="Choose one"></option>
                     <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
                     <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
                     <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
                     <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
                     <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
                  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers here didn't work for me, but this one is good:

```
  $('#modal-window').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#select-box").select2({
      placeholder: "Select...",
      theme: "bootstrap",
      language: "en"
    });
  })
```

Wrap it inside

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {...}
```

if you use turbolink.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i resolve this calling select2 on action modal show like this:

```
    window.addEventListener('showModal', event => {
        $('#actionModal').modal('show');
        $('#permissaoList').select2({
            width: '100%'
        });
    });
```