# What's the tabindex="-1" in bootstrap for

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

What's the `tabindex` attribute in Bootstrap 3 for?

Its documentation doesn't say anything about them although they use them practically in all modals.

I've only find this regarding its use, which doesn't really say much

> **Accessible tooltips for keyboard and assistive technology users**
>
> For users navigating with a keyboard, and in particular users of assistive technologies, you should only add tooltips to keyboard-focusable elements such as links, form controls, or any arbitrary element with a tabindex="0" attribute.

And I found out [I can't press `esc` to hide a modal if the `tabindex` attribute is not `-1`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4854).

- [Modal closing after pressing `esc` key (with tabindex)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz5c1v8d/)
- [Modal not closing after pressing `esc` key (without tabindex)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz5c1v8d/1/)

Comment: https://youtu.be/Pe0Ce1WtnUM

Answer (score 223, accepted):

> The `tabindex` attribute explicitly defines the navigation order for focusable elements (typically links and form controls) within a page. It can also be used to define whether elements should be focusable or not.
>
> [Both] `tabindex="0"` and `tabindex="-1"` have special meaning and provide distinct functionality in HTML. A value of `0` indicates that the element should be placed in the default navigation order. This allows elements that are not natively focusable (such as `<div>`, `<span>`, and `<p>`) to receive keyboard focus. Of course one should generally use links and form controls for all interactive elements, but this does allow other elements to be focusable and trigger interaction.
>
> A `tabindex="-1"` value **removes the element from the default navigation flow** (i.e., a user cannot tab to it), but it **allows it to receive programmatic focus**, meaning focus can be set to it from a link or with scripting.** This can be very **useful for elements that should not be tabbed to, but that may need to have focus set to them**.
>
> A good example is a **modal dialog window** - when opened, focus should be set to the dialog so a screen reader will begin **reading** and the keyboard will begin **navigating** within the dialog. Because the dialog (probably just a `<div>` element) is not focusable by default, assigning it `tabindex="-1"` allows focus to be set to it with scripting when it is presented.
>
> A value of `-1` can also be useful in complex widgets and menus that utilize arrow keys or **other shortcut keys** to ensure that only one element within the widget is navigable with the tab key, but still allow focus to be set on other components within the widget.

**Source:** http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex

This is why you need `tabindex="-1"` on the modal `<div>`, so users can access common mouse and keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: The attribute is part of HTML, it has nothing to do with Bootstrap specifically.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is being said here, that it's a "distinct functionality in HTML" and not something to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: To be able to focus on a <div> with JavaScript, the tabindex attribute MUST be defined on this element (any values such as tabindex=-1). If tabindex is not present on the div, focusing will not work. This is why BS adds tabindex=-1 to the modal div. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets: if tabindex is not present,  the focusable with JS will follow the platform convention of the element (yes for form controls, links, etc.). This means <div> is not focuable if tabindex is not present.

Comment: Worth adding that elements with tabindex="-1" are also focusable by clicking on them.

Answer (score 28):

The [tabindex](https://kolosek.com/tabindex/) attribute **is associated with HTML**, it is not specific to Bootstrap.

This property is responsible for indicating if an element is reachable by keyboard navigation.

You need to look out for three different scenarios:

1. When adding `tabindex = "0"` to an element this means it is reachable by the keyboard navigation but **the order is defined by the documents source order.**
2. When **adding a positive value** to the tabindex attribute (for example `tabindex = "1", tabindex = "2"`) those elements are reachable by keyboard navigation and the order **is defined by the value of the attribute.**
3. When **adding a negative value** to tabindex (usually `tabindex="-1"`) it means the element is **not reachable by the keyboard navigation, but can be focused using focus function in JS.**