# Bootstrap modal is closing for IE but not in firefox and chrome using ESCAPE key .

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/nrmja871/

if i run this fiddle in IE11 . after press **ESC** Key the bootstrap modal is closing but not in chrome or firefox.  I don't want to close the bootstrap modal using **ESC** key.

I read in bootstrap documentation([doc.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4663)) that we need to add `tabIndex='-1'` for closing the bootstrap modal using **ESC** key.

But why it is working in IE without using `tabIndex='-1'` ?

**PS**. don't give me solution saying use `"data-keyboard", "false"` for IE because i have to add this property for every modal :( .

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could find is in a  [discussion I found here about it from the twitter bootstap github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4663). Here's a quote from the conversation:

> This seems to be a breaking change in 2.1 as previously the keyup
>   event was bound to the document but now is bound to the actual modal
>   element. Hence, the the tabindex attribute is now required.

So basically when the JQuery library was updated from 2.0.X to 2.1.X the `keyup` event which was bound to the `document` element was changed so its now bound to the `modal` element which caused the escape keyup to not be recognized on some browsers which is why the `tabIndex='-1'` is now required.

This is how the tabindex helps

> A `tabindex="-1"` value removes the element from the default navigation
>   flow (i.e., a user cannot tab to it), but it allows it to receive
>   programmatic focus, meaning focus can be set to it from a link or with
>   scripting.** This can be very useful for elements that should not be
>   tabbed to, but that may need to have focus set to them.

This quote was taken from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911355/whats-the-tabindex-1-in-bootstrap-for) which has a great answer if you want to read up more on what the tabindex does. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks but what to do now for IE ? since still it doesn't required tabIndex='-1' for closing the modal using escape key ?