# Ensuring a drop-down selection box has keyboard access to fix axe violation(WCAG) - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts, wcag

So running [Axe](https://www.deque.com/axe/) (Web accessibility tool) on my web page produces a violation:

**Elements that have scrollable content should be accessible by keyboard**
*https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.3/scrollable-region-focusable?application=AxeChrome*

The link states that in order to fix it, the element should have focusable content or should be focusable. I can navigate to it by tabbing, however I am unable to expand the drop-down pressing the enter key. (Expands by pressing the up key)

How can i fix this so that my drop-down list can be expanded / triggered by pressing the enter key (assuming this is what will fix this error?)

[image]

My js code:

```
self.filterFields.forEach(x => {
                var titleDep = $('th[data-field="' + x + '"]');
                if (titleDep.find('select').length === 0 && self.foreignKeyData[x]) {
                    titleDep.append('<select aria-label="Filter ' + x + ' to show" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" tabindex="0" data-size="10"></select>');
                }
            });

            self.stringFilters.forEach(x => {
                var titleDep = $('th[data-field="' + x + '"]');
                if (titleDep.find('select').length === 0 && self.stringFilterValues[x]) {
                    titleDep.append('<select aria-label="Filter ' + x + ' to show" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" tabindex="0" data-size="10"></select>');     
                }
            });
```

I have tried fixing it by adding in

```
                titleDep.find('input').attr({ "tabindex": "0" });
                titleDep.find('input').attr({ "tabindex": 0 });
```

as well as `focusable="true"` and `autofocus` into the append statement but this doesn't work either.

However this doesn't seem to get me any closer to the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Is it just a regular `<select>` element or is there some kind of plugin which changes it (e.g. the popular Select2 plugin)? There could be an event listener modifying the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The error aXe is giving you is because there's a tabindex of -92 on the select element.  So you'd want to find out where that is coming from.  `<select>` elements should be tabbable by default with no need to add an explicit tabindex.  Anything with a negative tabindex is not keyboard accessible by definition. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32912224/3010362 for a good discussion of how tabindex works.  I can't tell from what you've provided what other code might be modifying the tabindex.