# Disable a javascript library for a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know if it is possible to disable a particular library for a particular div?

Actually I am having a webpage with a modal dialog. There are two select boxes. First one is outside of modal div, while second one is in the modal div.

The library I am using is [unicorn js](https://github.com/toddpress/Unicorn-js) and [unicorn tables js](https://code.google.com/p/veapon-com/source/browse/trunk/zipper/app/plugin/bootstrap/js/unicorn.tables.js?r=202) which implicitly calls

```
$('select').select2();
```

of [jquery select2 js](https://select2.github.io/). Thus the library is invoked on all select elements on the page. This causes the select box to become disabled in modal.
I removed the select box out of the modal and it works perfect. So I suspect the select js does not work well with modal dialogs(bootstrap modal dialogs to be particular).

So how do I go about in this scenario so that the select box in the modal is not affected by select js library?

Comment: You probably won't be able to use those libraries if their dependencies break things you need - you could fork, find something else, or roll your own to fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the `tabindex="-1"` on the modal dialog, this attribute on the container div break select2, remove `tabindex="-1"` attribute and it'll work fine.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I tried it BTW but same result :( still interested in your source of this answer

Comment: It's a known issue; you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835872/select2-not-working-inside-bootstrap-modal or here: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1645