# select2 keyboard issue on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have an issue with select2, when it is being used on mobile devices.
On click, the virtual keyboard is shown. I tried using something like

```
$('select').select2({
  shouldFocusInput: function (instance) {
        // Attempt to detect touch devices
        var supportsTouchEvents = (('ontouchstart' in window) ||
                                   (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));

        // Only devices which support touch events should be special cased
        if (!supportsTouchEvents) {
            return true;
        }

        // Never focus the input if search is disabled
        if (instance.opts.minimumResultsForSearch < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

with no success. Even if I try to simply use

```
shouldFocusInput: false
```

the search text keeps getting focused.

Comment: Why use select2 if you're not going to allow searching?

Comment: I do want to allow searching, I just need to remove the auto-focus on click.

Comment: That's what {shouldFocusInput: false} is about... 
I have no idea why it doesn't work. I also tried updating the library but nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried

```
minimumResultsForSearch = -1
```

post of issue: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1541

Comment: It definitely works better... but it still has quite a few issues. It only works for single selects(on multiple I still get the keyboard), and even there something weird goes on: when I click on the select element and it's on the upper half of the screen it works fine, when it's on the lower the keyboard pops up again... so frustrating.

Comment: Nevermind, it has probably got to do something with the phone options. When the select box overflows, the keyboard pops up. Thanks whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on mobile see if it works:

```
var $select2 = $('select').select2();

$select2.on('select2-open', function(e) {
    $('.select2-drop-active .select2-input').blur();
});
```

Comment: Now the dropdown won't open on the first click, but the keyboard does. Kinda the opposite of what I need. haha

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I apologize for the coffeescript ahead of time.

Instructions in words: when opening the select2 make the input read only. When the input is focused, remove readonly.

```
$(".location-select").on("select2:open", () ->
  $(".select2-search__field").attr("readonly", true)

  $(".select2-dropdown").bind("touchstart", (e) ->
    $target = $(e.target)
    if $target.hasClass("select2-search__field")
      $target.removeAttr("readonly").focus()
  )
)

$(".location-select").on("select2:close", () ->
  $(".select2-dropdown").unbind("touchstart")
  $(".select2-search__field").removeAttr("readonly")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Select2 now supports this behavior (see this [link for details](https://select2.org/searching#hiding-the-search-box))

On that link you will find:

**For Single Select:**

For single selects, Select2 allows you to hide the search box using the minimumResultsForSearch configuration option. In this example, we use the value Infinity to tell Select2 to never display the search box.

```js
$("#js-example-basic-hide-search").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

**And for Multi-Select:**

For multi-select boxes, there is no distinct search control. So, to disable search for multi-select boxes, you will need to set the disabled property to true whenever the dropdown is opened or closed:

```js
$('#js-example-basic-hide-search-multi').select2();

$('#js-example-basic-hide-search-multi').on('select2:opening select2:closing', function( event ) {
    var $searchfield = $(this).parent().find('.select2-search__field');
    $searchfield.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an if statement to find out if the input is focused and after that used props to turn its focus to false,It seems to work well.

```
$('.yourSelect2-continer').on('select2:open', function () {

        if ( $('.select2-search input').is(':focus') ) {

            $('.select2-search input').prop('focus', false);

        } else {

            $('.select2-search input').prop('focus', true);

        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select2-search input").prop("readonly", true);
```

Worked fine for me.
Make sure you use it after the table's data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late to share this fix.... But i believe it would help someone... The accepted answer removes input box from select2. If you want to remove only the keyboard popup (input focus) in mobile, Just copy and paste the script at the bottom of your page.

```
<script>
 $(".select2, .select2-multiple").on('select2:open', function (e) {
     $('.select2-search input').prop('focus',false);
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I previously answered another question relative to this one.

If you have a problem with the **iPad keyboard** which **hide** the **bootstrap modal** while **clicking on the select2 input**, I suggest you to check my answer : [Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal/48624008#48624008#answer-48624008).

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This works best:

```
minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
```

Here is a handy way to setup select2 boxes.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.teamsList').val('').change();
                $('.teamsList').prepend('<option></option>').select2({placeholder: 'Select or create new...', allowClear: true, width: '100%', minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity});
                $('.teamsList').prepend('<option value="0">Create new</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
$(".select2-selection--single").click(function(){
  $(".select2-search__field").attr("type","number");
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the div containing **.select2-search** and **.select2-focusser**. This fixes it:

```
    $('select').select2(
      minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    )
    .on('select2-opening', function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.select2-container').find('.select2-search, .select2-focusser').remove()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#country').on('select2-focus', function (e) /// country is the select2 field id
{
     $('.select2-container .select2-focusser').remove();
     $('.select2-search input').prop('focus',false).removeClass('select2-focused');
});
```