# Search not working in JQuery autocomplete drop down

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have JQuery autocomplete dropdown inside the bootstrap dialog in Angular JS application.

I can able to select the items in the dropdown, But can't able to search the items.

What is the Issue and how to solve this?

"It Is Working fine outside the bootstrap modal"

[image].

Comment: It's very hard to help you solve the problem if we only have an Image, Please post all relevant code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: can you reproduce it on a plnkr your post isnt very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are displaying items inside a dropdown using `ng-repeat`. If So, you can simply use Angular built-in `filter`. This is how it can look like, but I can't include that in your code, because you didn't provide it.

```
<div class="dropdown-options">
    <div class="filter-input-container">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="filter" />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="option-container" ng-repeat="option in listOptions | filter:searchText">
        <span>{{option.value}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code Angular will filter options insdie `listOption` by a keyword you will type in input box. You have to bind your input element to a `ng-model` which is in this case `searchText` (name could be whatever you want) and then you have to tell the `filter` what variable to use for filtering `filter:searchText`