# jQuery select2 automatic close immediate after opened

Tags: jquery-select2

The select2 is inside bootstrap 4 modal, and it only happen in modal.

[image: Select2 bug]

See the screenshot above, when I click on the element, it shows, then closed.

In the chrome console, I see these warning

```
[Violation] Avoid using document.write().
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 33ms
[Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 151ms
```

And here's my code

```js
$ele.select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#bootstrap4-modal'),
    ajax: {
        url: '/path/to/data',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term,
                start: ((params.page || 1) - 1) * 10,
                length: 10,
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.results,
                pagination: {
                    'more': (params.page * 10) < data.total
                }
            };
        }
    },
});
```

- OS: macOS Mojave
- Chrome: 73.0.3683.103 (64-bit)
- Bootstrap: v4.1.3
- select2: v4.0.5 *(with select2-bootstrap-theme/0.1.0-beta.10)*

P/S: It not always happen

Answer (score 7):

I think I've [found a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal/54100010#54100010), what I missing out is `.modal-content`

```js
dropdownParent: $('#bootstrap4-modal .modal-content'),
```

Now the select2 display correctly

Comment: Bless You! I was struggling trying to get this fixed!

Comment: finally, I don't have a modal, but still something in my page was triggering the focus, all select2 fields without search box were closing immediately. Weird that the "normal" fields with search box were working ok.