# Can I use two overflow properties?

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, overflow, jquery-select2

I am using Bootstrap and Select2.

I have encountered the unclickable search box error on Select2 which I fixed by adding `overflow: visible` on my modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true" style="overflow:visible">
```

But this caused my modal to be unscrollable. Changing it to `overflow:scroll` caused the previous Select2 error to re-appear.

How do I go about this? Can I use two overflow properties?

Comment: Never used Select2, but this sounds promising (since no example is present) - https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging Google for the solution that might work for me, finally I found the **real answer** from [here in pymarco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal/38550712). You have to add below code to your `$(document).ready(function() { });`

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

This made the Select2 search and the modal scrolling both working.