# The data of select 2 is misaligned

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have this modal with bootstrap 5 and select 2 but moving the modal messes up any selection and I don't know how to fix the data so it doesn't go elsewhere.

In the selects that are first, they are automatically selected when I click on the select and that is not the intention, but you can choose the data.

I don't know if that can be fixed with css or with the same configuration of select2 that I don't know.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  showSelect2();
});
    function showSelect2() {
        $('.class_active_search_select').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap-5",
            placeholder: "Seleccione",
            minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
            dropdownParent: $("#myModal"),
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            multiple: false,
            width: '100%',
            language: {
                noResults: function (term) {


                    return '<b>Sin coincidencias !!!</b>';
                }
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {

                if (markup === "Searching…") {
                    markup = "<b>Cargando datos... por favor espere !</b>";
                }


                return markup;
            },

            allowClear: true
        });

        $('.class_active_search_select').css('width', '100%');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container mt-3">
         <h3>Modal Example</h3>
         <p>Click on the button to open the modal.</p>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
         Open modal
         </button>
      </div>
      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="myModal">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <!-- Modal Header -->
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
               </div>
               <!-- Modal body -->
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <form id="NuevoForm" name="NuevoForm" class="formlogin was-validated">
                     <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <label>Nombre</label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <label>Branch</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" data-placeholder="select state" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="El nombre de la agencia puede contener mayúsculas y minúsculas, números y símbolos, el sistema toma como iguales las mayúsculas y minúsculas del mismo caracter" class="form-control tamanoInput" placeholder="Escriba un Nombre" required>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Escriba un Nombre.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input type="text" id="CodigoBranch" name="CodigoBranch" data-placeholder="select state" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Anote el branch asociado a la agencia según AS400" class="form-control tamanoInput" placeholder="Escriba un Branch" maxlength="4" required>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Escriba un Branch.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <label>Provincia</label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <label>Canton</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                              <select name="CodigoProvincia" id="CodigoProvincia" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Seleccione la Provincia en la que se encuentra la Agencia Bancaria" class="form-control class_active_search_select form-select" required="">
                                 <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Seleccione</option>
                                 <option value="1">CRC</option>
                                 <option value="2">USD</option>
                                 <option value="3">EUR</option>
                              </select>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Seleccione una provincia válida.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                              <select name="CodigoCanton" id="CodigoCanton" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Seleccione el Cantón al que pertenece la Agencia Bancaria" class="form-control class_active_search_select form-select" required="">
                                 <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Seleccione</option>
                                 <option value="1">CRC</option>
                                 <option value="2">USD</option>
                                 <option value="3">EUR</option>
                              </select>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Seleccione un canton válido.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <label>Distrito</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                              <select name="CodigoDistrito" id="CodigoDistrito" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Seleccione el Distrito al que pertece" class="form-control class_active_search_select form-select" required="">
                                 <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Seleccione</option>
                                 <option value="1">CRC</option>
                                 <option value="2">USD</option>
                                 <option value="3">EUR</option>
                              </select>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Seleccione un distrito válido.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                 <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="Activo" name="Activo" value="true" checked="checked">
                                 </div>
                                 <label class="position" data-placeholder="select state" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Marque Activar para que la agencia quede activa">Activar</label>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                              <label>Dirección</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <textarea class="form-control" data-placeholder="select state" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="La dirección puede contener números y letras, y tiene un máximo de 200 caracteres" name="Direccion" id="Direccion" rows="3" maxlength="200" required></textarea>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Escriba una dirección.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label>País</label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label>CEDI</label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label>Código de agencia</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                              <select name="CodigoPais" id="CodigoPais" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Seleccione el Distrito al que pertece" class="form-control class_active_search_select form-select" required="">
                                 <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Seleccione</option>
                                 <option value="1">CRC</option>
                                 <option value="2">USD</option>
                                 <option value="3">EUR</option>
                              </select>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Seleccione un pais válido.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                              <select name="CodigoCEDI" id="CodigoCEDI" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Seleccione un CEDI en la que se encuentra la Agencia Bancaria" class="form-control class_active_search_select form-select" required="">
                                 <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Seleccione</option>
                                 <option value="1">CRC</option>
                                 <option value="2">USD</option>
                                 <option value="3">EUR</option>
                              </select>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Seleccione un CEDI válido.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <input type="text" id="CodigoAgencia" name="CodigoAgencia" data-placeholder="" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Es un código de 5 dígitos numéricos que se crea automáticamente la primera vez que se crea el registro" class="form-control tamanoInput" placeholder="" maxlength="5" disabled>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label>Grupo de agencias</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 form-group">
                              <select name="CodigoGrupoAgencias" id="CodigoGrupoAgencias" data-toggle="tooltip-primary-gris" data-placement="top" title="Seleccione el grupo de agencia en la que se encuentra la Agencia Bancaria" class="form-control class_active_search_select form-select" required="">
                                 <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Seleccione</option>
                                 <option value="1">CRC</option>
                                 <option value="2">USD</option>
                                 <option value="3">EUR</option>
                              </select>
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                 Seleccione un grupo de agencia válido.
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <!-- Modal footer -->
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: See if [Beez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal/#answer-54100010) helps you.