# Select2 - Search is disabled - only first value from data is displayed

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery-select2

I am facing an issue with the select2 plugin. First of all, the search box seems to be disabled, even though, I could not find a property for this functionality in select2 plugin. Also, I have 3 elements in the data array and only the first one is shown ("a" in this case).
No error is displayed in console. 
Also, when I inspect the "select" element on the page, I can see the 3 options being created.

JSP File :

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="email" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label">Select Option</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select id="selectOpt" name="selectOpt"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS File :

```
$('#selectOpt').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Option',
    allowClear : false,
    cache : false,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    data : [{
              id : '0',
              text : 'a'
          },{ id : '1',
              text : 'b'
          },{
              id : '2',
              text : 'c'
          }
    ]   
});
```

Comment: The problem regarding the search was fixed. I had one dialog as a parent for the above div. Fixed the search using : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787982/select2-plugin-and-jquery-ui-modal-dialogs . But I still have the problem regarding the data array.

Comment: Although I found the root cause, I cannot understand why this little modification made the data items visible in select2. From the css found at the following link http://www.junctionartsfestival.com.au/resources/sass/third_party/_select2.scss , I kept this : 
.select2-search {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}